# jqplot with IE8 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jqplot

i am getting a js-error when i try to init graphs with jqplot under IE8.

The error is at:

```
return window.G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(P)
```

in the jquery.jqplot.min.js file.

The error is about: "the property initElement is undefined or null"

How can i fix that?

Moreover the same error appears at the [official site](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php) of jqplot.

I am using the IE11 with IE8 Emulator Mode.
IE>8 => no problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you include the `excanvas`?

[From their site](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html):

> Note, excanvas is required only for IE versions below 9.  IE 9
>   includes native support for the canvas element and does not require
>   excanvas

[Note, if you are using IE10+ and are emulation IE8, conditional comments does not work.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So instead of

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

try out

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script>
```

If it works then, it should work in the real IE8. You can keep the conditional comment or use feature dectetion to include the `excanvas.js`.

Comment: Thanks, that was my misstake. Without conditional comments its working!

Comment: Super, did it answer your question then?